# Unable to run flutter app on android with Flutter PDF View Package

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing this issue after trying to run flutter build apk/ flutter run on android simulator.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1
> Could not find com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.pom
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.pom
    - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.pom
  Required by:
      project :app > project :flutter_pdfview
```

I think it has smthg to do with the flutter_pdfview package [hERE](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview).

Hope to get any guidance on how to resolve this.

Comment: Please add what's the issue you are facing while building the apk.

Comment: Sorry, didnt double check my question, I have edited it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In pubspec.yaml add flutter_pdfview: any and try running it. If it doesn't work try on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Adding jCenter() to the your build.gradle in the android folder below will work for you. I was having similar challenge but after adding it , everything is now working fine for me

```
  allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
        }
       }
```